# Hadoop slave cannot connect to host

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have now completed the Hadoop standalone deployment without any errors, but I am trying to pseudo distribute Hadoop and found that the slave cannot connect to the host.The error log of the slave is like this：

The ‘hadoop-root-nodemanager-node-2.log’ is

```
2023-07-07 09:48:52,735 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8031. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2023-07-07 09:48:53,737 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8031. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

The ‘hadoop-root-datanode-node-2.log’ is

```
2023-07-07 09:50:18,090 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Block pool BP-1565964139-192.168.101.10-1688725270162 (Datanode Uuid 27e1a679-472d-47b1-a1ed-e8354f65b576) service to node-1/192.168.101.10:9000 beginning handshake with NN
2023-07-07 09:50:18,091 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Block pool BP-1565964139-192.168.101.10-1688725270162 (Datanode Uuid 27e1a679-472d-47b1-a1ed-e8354f65b576) service to node-1/192.168.101.10:9000 successfully registered with NN
```

I am sure that the host name and IP address of the slave are correct. As a beginner, I am not sure why this problem occurred. In addition, I have modified/hadoop/etc/hadoop/worker to the correct hostname. Please help me.

Comment: 1) `0.0.0.0` is not a routable IP address. Ensure the yarn-site or slaves file doesn't list any address with this 2) Your datanode log is fine - what's the problem? 3) You should not run these services as root user

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `yarn.resourcemanager.address` in yarm site xml in all your cluster including datanodes